# JS how to check if array .includes() in a string

Tags: javascript

i want to check if array includes in a string.

```
var arr = ['Hello','hi','John'];

var string = "Hello, my name is John";

var check = string.includes(arr);

output : true
```

Comment: you need to go the opposite way. some() and includes()

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "includes" means? E.g. does `"a"` include `["a", "a"]`? Why does `"Hello, my name is John"` include `['Hello', 'hi', 'John']`, when there is no `"hi"` anywhere in the string?

Comment: thank you for your answer but have any example?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see that string includes arr. Are you looking to see if any word in `arr` is in `string`? Then use `arr.some(e => string.includes(e))`.

Comment: i mean is if any array value matches in a string ..
if a string have "Hello" or "hi" i want to get output  " true "
if a string doesn't  have any in array output will be false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing it weird, but here you go:

```
var arr = ['Hello','hi','John'];
var string = "Hello, my name is John";
var check = arr.every(str => string.includes(str)) //-> false
```

The above checks to see that `every()` item in the array is in the string. The above would return `false` because the string "hi" is not present.

If you only want to check to make sure at least ONE item in the array is present in the string, you can use `some()`:

```
var check = arr.some(str => string.includes(str)) //-> true
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! this is what im looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if your condition is true for all elements inside the array:

```
arr.every( elem => string.includes(elem));
```